In Shortcuts, how can I convert a time in plain text into a date?
I want to be able to write a text like "155pm" and have that get turned into a date and then into an alarm on the same day with that time. I tried the set of actions shown below (link to shortcut), it works when I tried like "3pm" but not "155pm". Any ideas or solutions?


what should the system do with „115pm“, is this 01:15 or 11:05?

I get that but I want times to work if they're not in a formal / proper format but unambiguous, in this case 155pm is undoubtedly 1:55 PM.

You're going to have to write that sort of parser, if that's what you want.

I could make a simple regex one for one pattern of times, if I want something more versatile, I could call the Scriptable app from a shortcut and get the output of a script which could use a JS library to parse the text into a time.

Stick to using the 24 hour representation - little confusion then.
